# when & how dust.render will get call

Tags: dust.js

I have written dust js I call render function from my jquery local function.

Anyone please example how dust render get back. Do I need to call in onload function or not?

```
  dust.render("tmp_skill", json_object, function(err, html_out) {
          //HTML output
             $('#page').html(html_out);
              console.log(html_out);
          });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is ok, you can call the render method at any time. if you call it in the onload, you have to compile and load that template (tmp_skill) in the dust cache previously.

the steps to render dust are:

1) compile the template
2) load it to the dust cache with a name.
3) render the template

SO

```
var compiled = dust.compile("Hello world {name}", "tmp_skill");

dust.loadSource(compiled);

dust.render("tmp_skill", json_object, function(err, html_out) {
      //HTML output
         $('#page').html(html_out);
          console.log(html_out);
      });
```

Anything you need you can read our wiki. you will find a lot of documentation and examples here:  https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this question is related to your previous question, [How to write dustjs in php code without nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909293/how-to-write-dustjs-in-php-code-without-nodejs)

I tested your code and it works just fine.

do check your browser's console to see if there are errors after loading the page.

also, do use the linkedin fork of dust: https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs - it's much more actively developed.